# string to array?

Tags: c#

I have a string `"a b" "c" "d ef"` and I'd like to convert it to `string[]args` and have an array that is `{"a b", "c", "d ef"}`. How do I parse it?

Comment: If it's consistently separated by `" "` (so `"` <space> `"`) you could split it on that (maybe using a regexp as well) and then handle the start and end `"`. This might turn into issues if you want to be able to have `"a b" " " "cd"`.

Comment: Are you saying your string had embedded quotes, or is your example three separate strings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `String.Split`:

```
string[] args = str.Split(new[]{"\" \""},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(s => s.Trim('"')).ToArray();
```

or even more efficient:

```
args = str.Trim('"').Split(new[]{"\" \""},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
var originalString = "\"a b\" \"c\" \"d ef\"";
var args = originalString.Split('"').Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)).ToArray();
```